Problem with receiving data via UART on Linux Ubuntu for first time uppon boot
I have some weird problem with my console application. To make this short, my app is supposed to send and receive some Mavlink messages via UART, and my program stalls just when i start it first time after booting my PC. I discovered that when i sniff some packets using Serial Monitor extension in VSCode, or Hterm (it doesn't matter which of these two) and turn it off after receiving some data, when i try to start my app, it works great. After that ritual, i can start it without any problem every time. The most part of my app is written in C, and I have been using termios structure to configure UART, and i have used Cpp stadard library threads and queue. I have tested this app for 1000 times and after every boot, i must do that thing with Serial Monitor to make it work. Has someone experienced same issue?
This is the some C uart library functions that i have written for this console application:
#include "uart.h"



int UART0_Open(int fd,
               char *port)
{
    fd = open(port, O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NDELAY);
    if (fd == FAIL)
    {
        perror("Can't open serial port!\n");
        return FAIL;
    }
    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0) < 0)
    {
        printf("Fcntl fail!\n");
        return FAIL;
    } else {
        printf("Fcntl = %d\n", fcntl(fd, F_SETFL,0));
    }
    if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO) == 0)
    {
        printf("Standard input is not a terminal device\n");
        return FAIL;
    } else {
        printf("Isatty success\n");
    }
    printf("fd->open=%d\n", fd);
    return fd;
}

uart_status_t UART0_Set(int fd, 
              uart_baudrate_t     baudrate, 
              uart_flow_control_t flow_ctrl, 
              uart_databits_t     databits, 
              uart_stopbits_t     stopbits, 
              uart_parity_t       parity)
{
    int i;
    int status;

    struct termios options;
    if(tcgetattr(fd, &options)!=0)
    {
        perror("Setup UART\n");
        return FAIL;
    }

    /* Baudrate settings */
    
    switch(baudrate)
    {
        case BAUD_9600:
        {
            cfsetispeed(&options, B9600);
            cfsetospeed(&options, B9600);
            break;
        }
        case BAUD_19200:
        {
            cfsetispeed(&options, B19200);
            cfsetospeed(&options, B19200);
            break;
        }
        case BAUD_38400:
        {
            cfsetispeed(&options, B38400);
            cfsetospeed(&options, B38400);
            break;
        }
        case BAUD_115200:
        {
            cfsetispeed(&options, B115200);
            cfsetospeed(&options, B115200);
            break;
        }
        case BAUD_230400:
        {
            cfsetispeed(&options, B230400);
            cfsetospeed(&options, B230400);
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            perror("Unsupported UART baudrate!\n");
            return FAIL;
            break;
        }
    }
    

    options.c_cflag |= CLOCAL;
    options.c_cflag |= CREAD;
    
    /* Flow Control settings */
    switch(flow_ctrl)
    {
        case NO_FLOW_CTRL:  // No flow control is used
        {
            options.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
            break;
        }
        case HW_FLOW_CTRL:  // Hardware flow control
        {
            options.c_cflag |= CRTSCTS;
            break;
        }
        case SW_FLOW_CTRL:  // Software flow control
        {
            options.c_cflag |= IXON | IXOFF | IXANY;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;  // Mask other flag bits

    /* Databits settings */
    switch (databits)
    {
        case DATABIT_5:
        {
            options.c_cflag |= CS5;
            break;
        }
        case DATABIT_6:
        {
            options.c_cflag |= CS6;
            break;
        }
        case DATABIT_7:
        {
            options.c_cflag |= CS7;
            break;
        }
        case DATABIT_8:    
        {
            options.c_cflag |= CS8;
            break;  
        }
        default:   
            fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported data size\n");
            return FAIL;
    }

    /* Parity settings */
    switch(parity)
    {  
        case PARITY_NO: //No Parity bit
        {
            options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; 
            options.c_iflag &= ~INPCK;    
            break; 
        }
        case PARITY_ODD:    //Odd parity check
        {
            options.c_cflag |= (PARODD | PARENB); 
            options.c_iflag |= INPCK;             
            break; 
        }
        case PARITY_EVEN:   //Even parity check
        {
            options.c_cflag |= PARENB;       
            options.c_cflag &= ~PARODD;       
            options.c_iflag |= INPCK;       
            break;
        }
        case PARITY_SPACE:  //Space
        {
            options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
            options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
            break; 
        }
        default:  
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported parity\n");   
            return FAIL; 
        }
    } 

    //Set stop bit
    switch (stopbits)
    {  
        case STOPBIT_1:
        {   
            options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; 
            break; 
        }
        case STOPBIT_2:   
        {
            options.c_cflag |= CSTOPB; 
            break;
        }
        default:   
            fprintf(stderr,"Unsupported stop bits\n"); 
        return FAIL;
    }

    //Modify output mode, RAW data mode
    options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    //set the minimum waiting time and minimum receiving bytes before unblocking
    options.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
    options.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;

    tcflush(fd,TCIFLUSH);
    //active the configuration
    if(tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options) != 0)
    {
        perror("com set error!\n");  
        return FAIL; 
    }

    /* Delete this later */
    int bd = cfgetospeed(&options);
    

    if(tcgetattr(fd, &options) != 0)
    {
        perror("UART config not valid!\n");
        return FAIL;
    }
    printf("Configured baudrate: %d\n", UART0_GetOutputBaudrate(&options));

    //if(tcget)


    return SUCCESS;
}

int UART0_Recv(int fd, char *rcv_buf, int data_len)
{
    
    int len,fs_sel;
    fd_set fs_read;
    struct timeval time;

    FD_ZERO(&fs_read);
    FD_SET(fd, &fs_read);

    time.tv_sec = 10;
    time.tv_usec = 0;

    // Using Select() function to realize the multiply channels' communication

//  fs_sel = select(fd+1, &fs_read, NULL, NULL, &time);
//  if(fs_sel)
//  {
//      len = read(fd, rcv_buf, data_len);
//      return(len);
//  }
//  else
//  {
//      return FAIL;
//  } 
    
    return read(fd, rcv_buf, data_len);    
}

int UART0_Send(int fd, char *send_buf, int data_len)
{
    int len = 0;
    len = write(fd, send_buf, data_len);
    if(len == data_len)
    {
        return(len);
    }     
    else
    {
        tcflush(fd,TCOFLUSH);
        return FAIL;
    }
}

void UART0_Close(int fd)
{
    close(fd);
}

uart_baudrate_t UART0_GetInputBaudrate(struct termios *t)
{
    int bd = cfgetispeed(t);
    switch(bd)
    {
        case B9600:
        {
            return BAUD_9600;
        }
        case B19200:
        {
            return BAUD_19200;
        }
        case B38400:
        {
            return BAUD_38400;
        }
        case B115200:
        {
            return BAUD_115200;
        }
        case B230400:
        {
            return BAUD_230400;
        }
        default:
        {
            return FAIL;
        }
    }
}

uart_baudrate_t UART0_GetOutputBaudrate(struct termios *t)
{
    int bd = cfgetospeed(t);
    switch(bd)
    {
        case B9600:
        {
            return BAUD_9600;
        }
        case B19200:
        {
            return BAUD_19200;
        }
        case B38400:
        {
            return BAUD_38400;
        }
        case B115200:
        {
            return BAUD_115200;
        }
        case B230400:
        {
            return BAUD_230400;
        }
        default:
        {
            return FAIL;
        }
    }
}


I expect that problem lies in kernel buffer of Linux, but i may be very wrong.

Could you define "at boot"? Possibly you should try adding a delay. If it solve the problem, possibly you start too early: check boot dependencies (device tree ready, serial module on, serial ok).

By saying "at boot", I mean the moment when my PC is turned on.

Still I do not understand at boot. Boot process is long and complex. When and how do you start your program? Because your program fails at such point, but not later, I would assume (first checks: the simple things) that you miss some part of boot (so you run the program too early)

I solved this issue by adding these flags to my termios structure:
  `
options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
options.c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT | ICRNL | INPCK | ISTRIP | IXON);

  and by changing values of c_cc to zeroes:  
options.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
options.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
  `
Giacomo, by saying "at boot", I mean when I power cycle my PC, and my Linux is ready to be used, most basic startup - turning on my computer. My application does not start automatically or something, I manually start it in terminal, which is the whole idea with this app.

Does this answer your question? Can't read from serial port if not opened once with minicom
